# Remove mark selection values Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm trying to remove the mark selection, but I don't find the way to do that... 
I give you the link of the image below.

[image]

Theme --> Shady-Manokai
Netbeans version -->  8.0.2

Comment: Go to Tools -> options -> editor -> highlighting

Comment: There are bunch of options what shall I choose?

Comment: Don't know which mark occurences you want to enable/disable, you have to try it yourself.

Comment: "tipus" mark selection... it's like yellow and it doesn't let me read me properly.